# How can I run a locally installed mix task in the context of an app with a breakpoint?

Tags: elixir, breakpoints, elixir-mix, elixir-iex

I would like to run a locally installed mix task, (by which I mean a task installed  from another project using `mix archive.build; mix archive.install`) in the context of my app, but set a breakpoint first.

If I run `iex -S mix locally.installed.task`, that works fine. Of course the task has already run when I'm in my `iex` session.

That would be fine if I could subsequently run it again, after setting a breakpoint, like this:

```
break! Mix.Tasks.Locally.Installed.Task.run/1 #=> 1
Mix.Task.run("locally.installed.task", args)  #=> :noop
```

however this just returns `:noop` for my locally installed task, though it works for tasks defined in the app or for default global tasks like `mix deps`.

Why does `Mix.Task.run` return `:noop` for a "locally installed" task?

Is there any way to use IEX to run a mix task while setting the breakpoint first?

**edit:** the `:noop` is mix making tasks idempotent. I.E., if I do `iex -S mix deps`, and then run `Mix.Tasks.run("deps", [])` I also get `:noop, or if I run any given task in an` iex -S mix`session with`Mix.Task.run`it will only run once and subsequent invocations return`:noop`

There is a `Mix.Task.rerun/2` and that works...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As it said in docs, one should explicitly reenable the task with https://hexdocs.pm/mix/Mix.Task.html#reenable/1.

`rerun/1` would also work.

Comment: `reenable` works. I also found that if I launch `iex` with `iex -S mix help locally.installed.task` then all the code in the installed mix project is loaded, and I can set a breakpoint on that task or anywhere in the library, and then call `Mix.Task.run...`